# HTML and JavaScript not working as wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have created this script but it is not working as wanted:

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $('.textWord_about').hide();

        $('.link').click(function() {
        $('.textWord_about').hide();       
        $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
        }, 300);
        });


    </script>

</head>


<body>


<div style="float: left; width: 100%; height:100%;" >
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%; height:100% ">
            <table>
                <tr><td><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="82">Unit 1</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="158">Exam1</a></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div> 

        <div style="float: left; width: 33%; height:100%; " >

            <div class="textWord_about" data-link="82" >Overview   Vocabulary   Text   Homework   Homework2   Grammar   A_Vocabulary   </div>
            <div class="textWord_about" data-link="158" >ExamA   Exam2   </div>
        </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to change the content when you press Unit 1 or Exam 1.
I don't know why it is not working. The strange thing is that I copied and pasted everything in http://jsfiddle.net/CLVF3/ and it is working in the fiddle! I think I have done something wrong with the JavaScript part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your code inside [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.textWord_about').hide();
    $('.link').click(function() {
        $('.textWord_about').hide();       
        $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']')
        .fadeIn({ width: '200px' }, 300);
    });
});
```

Also you may just move the `script` to the bottom of the page, before the closing body-tag (`</body>`) as `Andy G` mentioned in the comment. The `$('.link').click()` event handler should be registered once the `DOM` is ready (when all elements are loaded).

Comment: Or just move the script to the bottom of the page, before the closing body-tag.

Comment: Yes, depends how young, or old, we are ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the script in a document ready function like this:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();

    $('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
    width: '200px'
    }, 300);
    });
});


</script>

</head>


<body>


<div style="float: left; width: 100%; height:100%;" >
    <div style="float: left; width: 33%; height:100% ">
        <table>
            <tr><td><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="82">Unit 1</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a class="link" href="#about" data-link="158">Exam1</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You mention `document.ready` but your code uses the `function()` shortcut, I think you should clarify this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(document).ready` for the javascript. Here is the plunker for the same https://plnkr.co/edit/Sl18DRNdu5rdFvTZbjJF?p=preview.